# How to cache images that can change later in IOS?

Tags: ios, caching

I am building a basic social app that have users and each have profile picture. I use Kingfisher to load their profile pictures with an url that is related to their userId.

For example: `www.myapp.com/users/user24932.jpg`

At the first load they load fine, but the problem is image is also cached. So if a person changes the profile picture from website, The iOS app still gets the same image from cache as url is still same.

But I also dont want to load the profile pictures every single time.

How do I handle caching in this case?

Comment: There is a standard mechanism for the implementation of cache. The server should return `304` status code to request the picture if it is not changed

Comment: @alex_p, Till how much time It will return the 304 status ? Means how do the server knows that Pic changed. Oh yes at a server side we can maintain this.

Comment: @MY Cool I want to know that what is "Kingfisher", and which framework/thirdparty you use to store the images in the cache. ?For my personal interest. Or it can help you to get the answer. Please updade.

Comment: Ok, Kingfisher is a Swift library to load image from url. Inspired by SDWebImage. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: @MY Cool, have you implemented anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a API service build stating that profile pic has been changed. 
Hence for new profile pic since last time (use timestamp) it should return 1 else 0.

If you get 1 download new profile pic and replaces the cached one.

So you new service will include a **boolean** **flag** and **timestamp**.

Comment: I agree with you, but we have to elaborate more, bit coding.!!??

Comment: Good idea, i will consider this!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following approach to solve the issue. By doing this, it will set the cached image as the placeholder and will replace the image only if there is any change. Let me know if you need any further help. Note:here i'm setting image of a button

```swift
                    self.avatar.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: imagelink), for: UIControl.State()){
                        result in
                        switch result{
                        case .success(let value): 
                        self.avatar.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: imagelink), for: UIControl.State(), placeholder: value.image,options: [.forceRefresh])
                        print("avatar set")
                            break
                        case .failure: print("not found in cache")
                            break
                        }
```